# Does the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}$ converge?

Is there a way to determine this besides a comparison test?

Comment: You can use the integral test if you don't like the comparison test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. The given series is *divergent*

- by comparison with the harmonic series: $$ \frac1n<\frac{\log n}n ,
     \qquad n \geq 3, $$
- by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence): $$ \frac{\log^2 N}2=\int_1^N \frac{\log   
     x}x\,dx\le\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log n}n $$ letting $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Why is that a hint?

Comment: This is more than a hint. This is nearly a complete answer. Nearly two complete answers for that matter.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a way besides the comparison test so this is perfect.